# Why does my ec2 instance respond so slow as compared to alb+lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am learning more about different AWS architectures and enjoying it.

I have one api service that uses php 8.2 + Laravel 10.2 and am load-testing it within 2 different architectures.

I tried the following 2 setups:

1. Application Load Balancer + Lambda serving my api under example.com/api/* paths
2. A single ec2 instance t3.small having nginx reverse proxy configured to forward the example.com/api/* requests to my docker container running the api

I use `vegeta` tool to make some small load-tests

```
echo "GET https://$host/api/load-data" | vegeta attack -rate=20/s -duration=10s | tee "$resultsFile" | vegeta report
```

The graph for the ec2 looks horrible. The response times do increase right away.

**ec2 results of the test**

```
Requests      [total, rate, throughput]         200, 20.10, 8.48
Duration      [total, attack, wait]             16.5s, 9.95s, 6.55s
Latencies     [min, mean, 50, 90, 95, 99, max]  501.875ms, 5.961s, 6.648s, 7.45s, 7.556s, 7.94s, 8.252s
Bytes In      [total, mean]                     4239103, 21195.51
Bytes Out     [total, mean]                     0, 0.00
Success       [ratio]                           70.00%
Status Codes  [code:count]                      200:140  429:60  
Error Set:
429 Too Many Requests
```

[image]

I monitored the ec2 cpu usage and it did not go over 8-9% which makes me confused why the result is so bad.

**The results of alb+lambda**
If I run the same test (same duration and config) against the load balancer + lambda architecture, the results look really good, will upload them later but there is no spike in response time it is rather constant.

**The rest of the infrastructure is the same for both scenarios.** They only depend on one AWS RDS Mysql instance located in the same vpc as the ec2  (or the lambda in the lambda scenario)

**Troubleshooting**
I am trying to understand the behaviour of the ec2 scenario and why this happens.
Why does this happen even though the cpu is used only 8% ? same for the free memory it has more than 1gb free.
Less than 10% cpu usage should not cause any throttling
[image]

Cpu credits are unlimited in my config
The cpu credits balance is also positive
[image]

The ec2 machine memory was more than enough, same as the cpu:
[image]

What do you think is the bottleneck and creates the issue ?
I want to fix this so the response time is more or less constant (like it is with alb+lambda combo) for this simple test with this throughput

Update:
I troubleshooted also with Newrelic apm and did notice that

- mysql was not the issue, the response time was always <= 200ms even under load
- most time >=6s was spent inside php. I am using Laravel and the trace said most time is inside `Custom/Illuminate\Foundation\Application::boot`
  Maybe this is one indication that the file-system is overloaded with many i/o but I don't know how to verify that. The disk write/bytes are not being shown in the ec2 monitoring

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions for speed improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I could speed up the response times in ec2 under the test by doing the following:

```
php artisan routes:cache
php artisan config:cache
```

The new results are

```
bash-5.1$ bash attack 
Requests      [total, rate, throughput]         200, 20.10, 13.66
Duration      [total, attack, wait]             10.247s, 9.949s, 298.284ms
Latencies     [min, mean, 50, 90, 95, 99, max]  289.23ms, 1.009s, 1.037s, 1.333s, 1.454s, 1.554s, 1.56s
Bytes In      [total, mean]                     4340606, 21703.03
Bytes Out     [total, mean]                     0, 0.00
Success       [ratio]                           70.00%
Status Codes  [code:count]                      200:140  429:60  
Error Set:
429 Too Many Requests
```

Almost 4 seconds less mean latency time, but still they increase and are like 3-4 times higher than the lambda + alb version.

It might be other ec2 processes probably but now am very happy that the difference is not so high as before.

I checked bref laravel-bridge and did notice that they run config:cache in the lambda which explains partially why the performance was so much better there.